# Clarification for a linear algebra problem stated: Find All Solutions to $AX = B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on a Linear Algebra HW problem which goes like:

Find all solutions $X = \left[\begin{matrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{matrix}\right]$ to the matrix equations $AX = B$ when $A = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right]$ and $B = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$

I know how to find a single solution to that problem, but I don't really know how to find all solutions.  I've looked in my book and class notes and I can't seem to find an example problem for all of the solutions.

As stated, this is a HW problem so I'm not looking for an answer, just some guidance or advice.

Thanks again in advanced for any help!

Comment: Maybe the question is worded badly. Maybe by saying "Find all solutions" they mean all the **components** of the matrix $X$, i.e. $x,y,z$ and $w$?

Comment: "Find all solutions" means that if there are no solutions, you should say so; if there's one, you should say so and write it down; and if there's more than one, you should find them all and write them down (or describe what they are in a simple way). This question wasn't revealing to you which of the three cases was applicable.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks again everyone!

Comment: If you want to check your solutions: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5B%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C3%7D%7D*%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%3D%7B%7B1%2C2%7D%2C%7B-1%2C2%7D%7D%2C%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%2Cd%7D%5D) you go! And don't forget to accept an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these steps:

(a) turn the matrix equation $AX = B$ into four linear equations.

(b) write the four equations as a matrix equation 
$A^\prime \pmatrix{x\\y\\z\\w} = b.$

(c) make the augmented matrix $A|b$ and row reduce.

(d) read the solution.

Comment: that's pretty much what I did.  We haven't been taught row reduction yet (even though I know it), so we're still putting the system of equations into triangular form and using back substitution.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one answer.

\begin{align}
  AX &= B\\
%
  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{bmatrix}
  &=
  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\\
%
  \begin{bmatrix}
     0x + 1z &  0y + 1w \\
    -1x + 3z & -1y + 3w
  \end{bmatrix}
  &=
  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\\
%
  \begin{bmatrix}
     z &  w \\
    -x + 3z & -y + 3w
  \end{bmatrix}
  &=
  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\\
  \\
     z &=  1 \\
     w &=  2 \\
 -x+3z &= -1 \\
 -y+3w &=  1 \\
  \\
     z &=  1 \\
     w &=  2 \\
  -x+3 &= -1 \\
  -y+6 &=  1 \\
\\
   z &=  1 \\
   w &=  2 \\
  -x &= -4 \\
  -y &= -5 \\
\\
  z &= 1 \\
  w &= 2 \\
  x &= 4 \\
  y &= 5 \\
\\
  X &= \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

### CHECK

$AX
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  4 & 5 \\
  1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   (0)(4) + (1)(1) &  (0)(5) + (1)(2) \\
  (-1)(4) + (3)(1) & (-1)(5) + (3)(2)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 \\
  -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
B
$